# How to send message from Unity to SignalR Self Hosted server using asp.net signal R and not asp.netcore

Tags: asp.net, unity-game-engine, signalr, chat

I am trying to create a chat application in a Unity game. So basically in one instance of the game if someone sends a message , all the other open instances of the game should get the message.

I successfully created a self-hosted SignalR 2 server using [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/deployment/tutorial-signalr-self-host)

The code for the console app is as follows:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Cors;

namespace SignalRSelfHost
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // This will *ONLY* bind to localhost, if you want to bind to all addresses
            // use http://*:8080 to bind to all addresses. 
            // See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx 
            // for more information.
            string url = "http://localhost:8080";//a web application of type Startup is started at the specified URL (http://localhost:8080). 
            using (WebApp.Start(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    class Startup
    {// the class containing the configuration for the SignalR server ,which creates routes for any Hub objects in the project.
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.MapSignalR();
        }
    }
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {//the SignalR Hub class that the application will provide to clients.
        public void Send(string name, string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addMessage(name, message);//clients will call to broadcast a message to all other connected clients.
        }
    }
}
```

I created a dummy Unity game as of now. There are the username input field and chat input field. Next to the chat input field there is a send button. So the person enters his/her name and enters something into the chat and all running instances of the game should receive the message , but I am not able to achieve that thing

The script for this is attached to a empty GameObject SignalRManager. The code is as follows:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using TMPro;

public class SignalRManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    string url = "http://localhost:8080";
    HubConnection connection;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject ChatMessage;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject UserName;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        connection = new HubConnection(url);
        connection.Start();
        connection.StateChanged += connection_StateChanged;
    }

    private void connection_StateChanged(StateChange state)
    {
       if(state.NewState== ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            Debug.Log("Connected to Server");
         }
       if(state.NewState == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
        {
            Debug.Log("Disconnected from Server");
        }
    }
   

    public void OnClickSendChatButton()
    {
        string message= ChatMessage.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
        string userName= UserName.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;

    }
   
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        connection.StateChanged -= connection_StateChanged;
    }
}
```

I am able to connect to the server as the log message appears , but dont know what to write to send message to the server. Also how do I receive the message from the server as well

I tried to use a function called connection.Send(), but it is not accepting two arguments. I tried to look into many tutorials ,but many are for asp.netcore Signal r , but I need it for asp.net signalR because thats my requirement.

<<<<--------edit------>>>

```
I was able to send data to the server but I am not able to receive data from the server on my Unity game. The updated code is as follows:

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;
using TMPro;

public class SignalRManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    string url = "http://localhost:8080";
    HubConnection connection;
    IHubProxy hubProxy;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject ChatMessage;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject UserName;
    [SerializeField] private TextMeshProUGUI OutputText;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        connection = new HubConnection(url);//Create a connection for the SignalR server
        hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");//Get a proxy object that will be used to interact with the specific hub on the server.There may be many hubs hosted on the server, so provide the type name for the hub
       
        
        connection.Start();
        connection.StateChanged += connection_StateChanged;
        
        OutputText.text = "";
    }

    private void OnReceivedMessageFromServer(string name, string message)
    {
        OutputText.text = OutputText.text+name + ":" + message + "\n";
        Debug.Log(OutputText.text + name + ":" + message + "\n");
    }

    private void connection_StateChanged(StateChange state)
    {
       if(state.NewState== ConnectionState.Connected)
        {
            Debug.Log("Connected to Server");
         }
       if(state.NewState == ConnectionState.Disconnected)
        {
            Debug.Log("Disconnected from Server");
        }
    }

   
   

    public void OnClickSendChatButton()
    {
        string message= ChatMessage.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
        string userName= UserName.GetComponent<TMP_InputField>().text;
        hubProxy.On<string, string>("addMessage", OnReceivedMessageFromServer);//register hub events (methods invoked by the hub). The following code registers a handler method for ChatMessage event.
        hubProxy.Invoke("Send", userName, message);
     }
   
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        connection.StateChanged -= connection_StateChanged;
    }
}
```

The callBack OnReceivedMessageFromServer is not invoked. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Did you try Invoke?

Comment: @AbhilashK I was able to . Please see updated code. But I am not able to receive the data on my client(Unity)

Comment: Call `hubProxy.On...` before starting the connection.

Comment: @ChethanVenkataramaiah I had a similar issue in the past and it was fixed by making the recieving function async. In my case I used UnityMainthreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue() to queue the calls that I recieve from the SignalR hub.

Comment: I think the correction @Brennan gave works fine. The problem was I was not able to see the changes in the UI and then thought that something was wrong in the code. The problem with text UI was that it was not refreshing so as to see the changes. I solved the issue as such with a small piece of code. Anyhow ppl can refer to this link to see a good look of what SIgnal R concepts https://www.codeguru.com/blog/how-to-push-data-from-server-to-client-using-signalr/#:~:text=Open%20Visual%20Studio%20and%20create,and%20name%20it%20as%20MyChatHub.